# Fixing 'define' is not defined no-undef in react create app third party imports

Tags: reactjs, webpack, amd, create-react-app

i have imported momentjs in my react app, after importing react create app is throwing following error restricting the build

> ./src/shared_components/quiz-player/node_modules/moment/moment.js
>   Line 9:  'define' is not defined  no-undef

when i investigate the issue it is thrown from following line

```
typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
global.moment = factory()
```

this is due to amd module definition and since this is a third party library i have no option of resolving the issue, is there any thing that can be done to tell the webpack config to expect amd module definition or some other fix for this?

Comment: use target option

Comment: @ReiDien target option is set for web, with search results i learned that it should be set for web to resolve this issue, but it didn't help? is there other option than web you suggest?

Comment: @RanganaSampath any solutions?

Comment: Any solution found?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to the tsconfig.json file at the root level of your project folder:

```
{"skipLibCheck": true,}
```

This should solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
...

/* eslint no-undef: */
typeof define === 'function' && define.amd 
  ? define(factory) 
  : global.moment = factory();

...
```

more see https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-undef

Answer (score -1):

Since the code is perfectly acceptable code that you don't want to touch, the easy solution is to make ESLint ignore the issue.  ESLint is being more aggressive than necessary, in this case.

There are (at least) a couple of ways to make the issue go away.

You can put a comment in the problem file that just literally makes the error go away:

```
    /* eslint no-undef: "off" */
```

Or, if you want to avoid that sort of blanket rule, you can tell ESLint that it's a global variable provided by the package, with a similar sort of comment:

```
    /* global define */
```